# GA4 purchase disappear after 24h

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-4

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with the purchase event in GA4.

Here is the JSON I'm posting. Everything seems to be working fine. I can see the purchase in the real-time view, and I can also see it the day after. However, suddenly it disappears from the monetization reports. Do I need to configure something in GA4 to make it visible?

Thank you.

```
{
    "client_id": "server",
    "events": {
        "name": "purchase",
        "params": {
            "transaction_id": "n8ndfsck",
            "value": "12.36",
            "tax": "1.61",
            "currency": "CAD",
            "isUpdate": "true",
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "COMPLET",
                    "item_name": "Avancé",
                    "price": "6.99",
                    "quantity": "1"
                },
                {
                    "item_id": "COMPLET2100",
                    "item_name": "Pro",
                    "price": "12.99",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The event in GA4

[image]
[image]
[image]

The transaction show in the monetization overview at 6h52 AM 7/11/2023
[image]

And the result at 9h46 AM the 7/11/2023
[image]